# Creating Common Post Angular Api and it's giving error

Tags: angular

Angular is new to me. I'm attempting to use an angular service to construct a typical Postdata call. But it's producing an error.
Anyone know what I'm missing in the code?

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpEvent,HttpHeaders, HttpParams  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestDService {

    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl:string
    ) {}

    private postData(apiUrl: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(
            this.baseUrl+apiUrl,
            body
            { headers: headers }
        ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

This line `return this.httpClient.post\<any\>(this.baseUrl+apiUrl,body,{headers:headers});` giving me error as Type 'Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, _trySubscribe, _subscribe, buffer, and 107 more.ts(2740)

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

Comment: Try importing from 'rxjs' and not 'rxjs/Observable'.

Comment: I tried importing from rxjs but still its giving error. in above example i added service code. 

"Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.ts(2740)"

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly copied your code, you have two mistakes:

1. you're missing a comma beteween `body` and the object containing your headers.
2. you're returnin a `Subscription` instead of an `Observable`

This is how your `postData` method should look like:

```js
private postData(apiUrl: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(
        this.baseUrl + apiUrl,
        body,
        {headers: headers}
    )
}
```